# Shinobi Chart initial data zoomed out

Tags: shinobi

is there way to set a starting zoom out value for [shinobi charts](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts)?

I already tried setting back one date to starting date and adding a date to ending date for the SChartDateRange (X axis) but no resolve.

Thanks in advance!

***Current Table & Axis Setup***

```
 //properties
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: UIView!
private var chart:ShinobiChart?
private let chartDataSource = LineGraphModDataSource()


//methods
override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()

chart = ShinobiChart(frame: chartView.bounds)
chartView.addSubview(chart!)

self.setupChart()

}//eom

func setupChart()
{
    chart?.delegate = self
    chart?.licenseKey =  Constants.shared.getLicenseKey()
    chart?.title             = "Chart #9"
    chart?.autoresizingMask  = [.flexibleHeight , .flexibleWidth]
    chart?.datasource = chartDataSource

/* X axis - Dates */
let dateRange:SChartDateRange = chartDataSource.getInititalDateRange()
chart?.xAxis = SChartDateTimeAxis()
chart?.xAxis.range = dateRange
chart?.xAxis.axisPosition = SChartAxisPositionNormal
chart?.xAxis.title = "Dates"
chart?.xAxis.labelFormatString = "MM dd yy"
chart?.xAxis.majorTickFrequency = SChartDateFrequency.dateFrequency(withDay: 3)
chart?.xAxis.minorTickFrequency = SChartDateFrequency.dateFrequency(withDay: 1)

//style
    //major
chart?.xAxis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = true
chart?.xAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showTicks = true
chart?.xAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showLabels = true

    //minor
chart?.xAxis.style.minorTickStyle.showTicks = true
chart?.xAxis.style.minorTickStyle.showLabels = true

//axis movement
chart?.xAxis.enableGesturePanning = true
chart?.xAxis.enableGestureZooming = true
chart?.xAxis.enableMomentumPanning = true
chart?.xAxis.enableMomentumZooming = true

/* Y axis - Values */
chart?.yAxis = SChartNumberAxis()
chart?.yAxis.defaultRange = SChartRange(minimum: 0, andMaximum: 10)
chart?.yAxis.title = "Y axis"
chart?.yAxis.axisPosition = SChartAxisPositionReverse
chart?.yAxis.majorTickFrequency = 1
chart?.yAxis.minorTickFrequency = 1
chart?.yAxis.rangePaddingLow = 0.5
chart?.yAxis.rangePaddingHigh = 0.5


//style
chart?.yAxis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = true
chart?.yAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showTicks = true
chart?.yAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showLabels = true
chart?.yAxis.style.minorTickStyle.showTicks = true
chart?.yAxis.style.minorTickStyle.showLabels = true

//axis movement
chart?.yAxis.enableGesturePanning = true
chart?.yAxis.enableGestureZooming = true
chart?.yAxis.enableMomentumPanning = true
chart?.yAxis.enableMomentumZooming = true
```

}//eom

**Current starting graph**
[image: Current starting graph]

**Desired starting graph**
[image: Desired starting graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to achieve this by specifying an initial data range when creating the chart.

In addition to providing a data range, the date range must be expanded so the graph can seem zoomed out as soon it loads.

For example, 
lets say that your initial date range:

- 8/21/16
- 8/25/16

The first date on your range must be rolled back 1 day and the last day must be moved up  1 day. So the range would become:

- 8/20/16
- 8/26/16

  **View Controller**

  ```
  SChartDateRange * startingDateRange = [self.datasource getInitialDateRange];
  self.chart.xAxis = [[SChartDateTimeAxis alloc] initWithRange:startingDateRange];
  self.chart.xAxis.majorTickFrequency = [[SChartDateFrequency alloc]initWithDay:1];
  ```

  **Datasource**

  -(SChartDateRange *)getInitialDateRange
    {

  ```
   NSInteger lastIndex = [self.afterData count];
  lastIndex = lastIndex-1;

  NSDate * minDate = [self getDateFromIndex:0];
  NSDate * maxDate = [self getDateFromIndex:lastIndex];

  //expanding range by 1 day so its more visible on map
  NSInteger secondInDay = 86164;
  minDate = [minDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondInDay];
  maxDate = [maxDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondInDay];

  SChartDateRange * range = [[SChartDateRange alloc]initWithDateMinimum:minDate andDateMaximum:maxDate];

  return range;
  ```

  }//eom